# Flutter Image Picker not saved to Path

Tags: android, flutter, path, imagepicker

I am using image_picker: ^0.8.4+2  _package to load and save image to device path, both from  gallery and camera in my flutter project.

The code runs well with no error or whatsoever.

But I found **the app does not load any permission** the first time it accessed gallery or camera. And the image I loaded whether from gallery or camera **was not saved and retrieved** when the app was hot restarted.
What did I miss?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Credit to Johannes Milke
https://youtu.be/MSv38jO4EJk

Here's the full code:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  File? _image;

  Future<File?> saveImagePermanently(String? imagePath) async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final name = basename(imagePath!);
    final image = File('${directory.path}/$name');
    return File(imagePath).copy(image.path);
  }

  Future loadImage(ImageSource? imageSource) async {
    try {
      final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: imageSource!);
      if (image == null) return;
      final imagePermanent = await saveImagePermanently(image.path);
      setState(() => _image = imagePermanent);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      Get.dialog(Center(
        child: Text('Failed to load image $e'),
      ));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              child: _image != null
                  ? Image.file(_image!)
                  : Container(
                      color: Colors.grey[300],
                    ),
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: const Text(
                'camera',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                loadImage(ImageSource.camera);
              },
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: const Text(
                'galery',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                loadImage(ImageSource.gallery);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  File? _image;

  Future<File?> saveImagePermanently(String? imagePath) async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final name = basename(imagePath!);
    final image = File('${directory.path}/$name');
    return File(imagePath).copy(image.path);
  }

  //
  // Future loadImage(ImageSource? imageSource) async {
  //   try {
  //     final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: imageSource!);
  //     if (image == null) return;
  //     final imagePermanent = await saveImagePermanently(image.path);
  //     setState(() => _image = imagePermanent);
  //   } on PlatformException catch (e) {
  //     Get.dialog(Center(
  //       child: Text('Failed to load image $e'),
  //     ));
  //   }
  // }
  
  /// Get from gallery
  _getFromGallery() async {
    PickedFile? pickedFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
      maxWidth: 1800,
      maxHeight: 1800,
    );
    if (pickedFile != null) {
      setState(() {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
      });
    }
  }

  /// Get from Camera
  _getFromCamera() async {
    PickedFile? pickedFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
      maxWidth: 1800,
      maxHeight: 1800,
    );
    if (pickedFile != null) {
      setState(() {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              child: _image != null
                  ? Image.file(
                      _image!,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    )
                  : Container(
                      color: Colors.grey[300],
                    ),
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: const Text(
                'camera',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                _getFromCamera();
              },
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: const Text(
                'galery',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                _getFromGallery();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And for the Permission: https://www.androidbugfix.com/2021/09/flutter-image-picker-explicitly-ask.html